# Ruby on Rails, checkbox array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am new to ruby and rails, and I can't seem to figure out how to use checkboxes for an array (they seem to be geared up only for single value, on/off style checkboxes), where as I want to select multiple values.

Using this [bootstrap gem](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms), I have managed to get it outputting correctly:

```
<%= f.form_group :cars, label: { text: "Cars" } do %>
    <% @cars.each do |car| %>
        <%= f.check_box :cars, {value: car, inline: true}, car do %>
            <%= car %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

...however the names of the fields are outputting as:

```
<input id="cfg_cars" type="checkbox" value="lotus_evora_gtc" name="cfg[cars]">
```

where as I want it to be:

```
<input id="cfg_cars" type="checkbox" value="lotus_evora_gtc" name="cfg[cars][]">
```

So I can join the values altogether into a string.

**My Question:** How do I get rails to play nice with checkbox arrays?

Comment: Try giving it like this `<%= f.check_box 'cars[]', {value: car, inline: true}, car do %>` and also i guess you should use `collection_check_boxes`.

Comment: May be not! `<%= f.check_box 'cars[]', {value: car, inline: true}, car do %>` should be enough.

Comment: @Pavan thanks, but that gives me - undefined method `cars[]'

Comment: Try this `<%= f.check_box 'car[]', {value: car, inline: true}, car do %>`

Comment: @Horse It doesn't seem to be documented, but when you take a look at the [CollectionCheckBoxes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.6/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_check_boxes.rb#L18) class code, you will see that it sets the option `multiple: true` for the CheckBoxBuilder instance. You can use this option on `check_box` too.